# Live stream to a URL and simultaneously store a rotated version to an SD card

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, ffmpeg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m trying to put together a script in FFmpeg that will command a 1) live stream to URL 2) save to SD card location  3) rotate my video by 90 degrees … Is that something you can put together and I can plug in to my system? I'm using an embedded Linux system in Windows.

Here is a better understanding of what I'm doing. I am using an embedded IoT device and the goal is to use FFmpeg to speed up my encoding and decoding while live streaming and saving to SD card and so far I haven't been able to successfully complete. This is what i have but still ended in an error:

```
ffmpeg -f v412 -input_format mjpeg-i/dev/video -r 10 -b:v 4000k -s 256x144 -c:v libx264 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://192.168.7.1:11795? pkt_size-1024"
```

This is the command I used and didn't work on my embedded system. What did I do wrong?

```
ffmpeg -y -i /mnt/mmcblk0p1/video/raw_stream.mjpeg /mnt/mmcblk0p1/video/stream.mp4 -f v412 -input_format mjpeg-i/dev/video -r 10 -b:v 4000k -s 256x144 -c:v libx264 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://192.168.7.1:11795? pkt_size-1024"
```

This was the response I got:

```
libswscale 4. 8.100 / 4. 8.100 libswresample 2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100 Trailing options were found on the commandline. [mjpeg @ 0x76bf1860] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible! Input #0, mjpeg, from '/mnt/mmcblk0p1/video/raw_stream.mjpeg': Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg4 (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [swscaler @ 0x9f6150] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly Output #0, mp4, to '/mnt/mmcblk0p1/video/stream.mp4': Metadata: encoder : Lavf57.83.100 Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc Metadata: encoder : Lavc57.107.100 mpeg4 Side data: cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
```

This is the full response to my command.

Comment: Could you try if this command executes without errors: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=clock" rotated.mp4 udp://127.0.0.1:1234`? Of course you have to change `input.mp4`, `rotated.mp4` and `udp://127.0.0.1:1234` to fit your needs.

Comment: If the suggested command worked, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer

This doesn't answer the updated version of the question. The answer was written with the old question in mind, which was unclear and didn't contain enough information! I will update my answer soon.

---

I am not entirely sure I understand you correctly, but if you want to download a video, rotate it by 90°, and save the video to an SD card, this is how you would do it...

---

#### Installation

Install FFmpeg and [Youtube-dl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube-dl):

```
# apt install ffmpeg youtube-dl
```

---

#### Commands

Download the video using Youtube-dl:

```
$ youtube-dl -o original_video.mp4 https://example.com/video
```

Rotate the video by 90° clockwise with the [FFmpeg transpose filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose):

```
$ ffmpeg -i original_video.mp4 -vf "transpose=clock" rotated_video.mp4
```

Move the video to the mounted SD card:

```
# mv rotated_video.mp4 /path/to/sd_card
```

---

#### Bash script

The above commands can be simplified and be put into a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

youtube-dl -o - $1 | ffmpeg -i - -vf "transpose=clock" $2
```

Make the script executable:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

The script can then be run with two arguments:

```
# ./script.sh https://example.com/video /path/to/sd_card/rotated_video.mp4
```

Comment: you are correct, but the proper edicate is something i wish to lean. don't mean any disrespect i am new to this industry, definitely took what was suggested  and tried it out. still no turn out. not sure wha t i am doing wrong but  trial and error is apart of this kind of learning

Comment: @LouisABarham - **Please don’t use the comment section to provide an output to a commands** The output is unreadable since it’s not formatted which makes the comment unnecessary. You really should just edit your question, however, you have already invalidated your only answer with your last edit.

Comment: @Ramhound I am going to do that. And it wasn't my idea to use the comment section for important information. I just read the missing information under my answer a few minutes ago.